# How to get list of played pdocasts in Itunes so that I select which to delete?

Tags: itunes, podcasts, macos

In iTunes, I want to be able to pull up a list of played podcasts from time to time and select some for deletion.

I don't want to auto-delete podcasts marked as played as a) I share the library with my wife and don't want podcasts to disappear if only one of us has listened to them and b) I want to be able to keep some favourites.

I can get the list of played podcasts by setting up a smart playlist of media kind=podcast, but I can't delete them using that list because it is just a playlist.  I can see what I want to delete, but I then have to go back the podcast view and find and delete each one individually, which seems clumsy.

Any ideas?

Billy

Comment: What prevents you from using the podcast view directly to delete them?

Answer (score 1):

Create a smart playlist with the criteria “Media kind is Podcast” and ”Plays is larger than 0”. Looks like this: [image]

Comment: OK, but like I said, that gives me a list that I can't delete from - am I missing something?  If I delete an entry from a playlist it doesn't delete the podcast, which is what I am trying to do.

Comment: Did you try ⌘⌫ (command backspace) to delete files?